# How to send data with angularjs $http.delete() request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-4

I have a resource 'roles' which has a many to many relationship with 'user'.  To administer 'roles' I need to send the role id and the user id to the server so that it removes the the role from the correct user (not necessarily the logged in user)

Here is what I was attempting but according to the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#delete) this is not possible.  I know I can send the two ids in the uri but my laravel backend automatically sets up a resourceful route of resource/{resourceid} which I would like to use if possible.  Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

```
var removeRole = function (roleid, userid) {
        var input =[];
        input.user = userid;

        $http.delete('/roles/' + roleid, input).success(function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can do an http DELETE via a URL like /users/1/roles/2. That would be the most RESTful way to do it.

Otherwise I guess you can just pass the user id as part of the query params?  Something like

```
$http.delete('/roles/' + roleid, {params: {userId: userID}}).then...
```

Comment: I declared a route /roles/1/users/1 and all is good in the world thanks

Comment: Good tip, i was trying without key `params` as get is but to delete request only work with `params` key, thanks much !

Comment: If you're looking to send via the body so you can access (for example) in node.js using req.body, try setting the header like @eldes answer.  Then you can use the shorthand $http.delete(<url>, <json-data>).then ...

Answer (score 39):

My suggestion:

```
$http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: '/roles/' + roleid,
    data: {
        user: userId
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}, function(rejection) {
    console.log(rejection.data);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`$http.delete` method doesn't accept request body.
You can try this workaround :

```
$http( angular.merge({}, config || {}, {
    method  : 'delete',
    url     : _url,
    data    : _data
}));
```

where in `config` you can pass config data like headers etc.

Comment: worked for me after I serialized the data.  params did not; that puts the data on the url; like so:   like http://example.com/getIdeas?foo=bar&baz=boo
where the params are after the question mark

Answer (score 3):

A many to many relationship normally has a linking table.  Consider this "link" as an entity in its own right and give it a unique id, then send that id in the delete request.

You would have a a REST resource URL like /user/role to handle operations on a user-role "link" entity.

Comment: I liked this answer but laravel has a handy detach() method for many to many relationships that deals with the pivot table for you once you have the relationships set up correctly so if I can get the userid to the delete method for that resource it is super easy from then on

Comment: It would seem like laravel should also provide a handy REST resource for deleting a many to many relationship, but I'm not familiar with laravel.  There's also some confusion about whether you can actually send data in a DELETE request.  There's a long discussion here:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3207

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading this url
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

and revaluate how you are calling your delete method of your resources.

ideally you would want to be calling the delete of the resource item itself and by not passing the id of the resource into a catch all delete method

however $http.delete accepts a config object that contains both url and data properties you could either craft the query string there or pass an object/string into the data

maybe something along these lines

```
$http.delete('/roles/'+roleid, {data: input});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not sure what you mean bu=y catch all delete method.  I am trying to call the roles delete method specifically by using a route /roles. so it is very specifically for that particular resource(as far as my understanding goes anyway).  That specific delete method just happens to also require the userid as well as the resource id

Comment: what i meant by that is not calling the $http.delete() directly, let your rest resource return a collection of resource items with the parameters of their actions already in place... so that you can call for instance data.items[0].delete(); rather than having to pass ids and things around

Comment: But what if you want to delete say 10000 entries and you want to just provide a list of IDs to your backend. 10000 separate requests would mean a lot of overhead. So a DELETE with body would be way more efficient.

Comment: I can't get `data` to work with $http.delete.  `params` works though.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to pass parameters in `httpoptions`, you can follow function below

```js
deleteAction(url, data) {
    const authToken = sessionStorage.getItem('authtoken');
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken,
      }),
      body: data,
    };
    return this.client.delete(url, options);
  }
```