# Using Angular $http.delete causing a TypeError

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to send a DELETE command using $http.delete but am getting an error:

**`TypeError --> Cannot create property 'method' on string 'user_id=5&response=This+is+a+test.'`**

when I execute the command in the controller as follows:

In the controller:

```
.controller(myController', function($scope) {

    var something = {
      user_id: 1,
      text: 'This is a test.'
    }

     MyFactory.deleteSomething(something);
});
```

In the service:

```
.factory('MyFactory', function($http) {

var service = {};

service.deleteSomething = function(something) {

var data = $.param(something);
var promise =  $http.delete('http://example.com/myapp.php?',
data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  }
})
  .success(function(data,status) {
    console.log("Delete success!");
    return data;
  })
  .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
    console.log("Delete FAILED!");
  });
return promise;
   }
return service;
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter `delete()` expects is an object with http request configuration. Not some string as you are passing `data`:

`$http.delete('http://example.com/myapp.php?',
data, {
[...]`

Comment: Isn't that what `var data = $.param(something);` is for? Just going by [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055251/sending-data-with-angularjs-http-delete-request).

Comment: As you can see in your own error message, `$.param(something)` is returning a string containing query parameters based on a object `'user_id=5&response=This+is+a+test.'` You would probably want something that does the opposite of that.

Comment: This solved it:    Change `var data = $.param(something);` to `var data = {params: something};`