# Sending data through DELETE method in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sql-delete

I am sending a key through DELETE method but the method seems inappropriate. Any clue what I am missing ? The function runs but the it does not work

```
$scope.delete = function(id) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the user") === true) {
    $http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'http://abc.dev/users/user/' + id,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      })
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.singleuser = data;
        console.log("function single user is processed");                   
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        console.log('error');
      });
  } else {
    console.log("no");
  }
};
```

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: Is the server allowing `delete` methods? Do you get a 403 response?

Comment: What doesn't work? Is neither of success of error callbacks getting called? Are you getting any errors in the JS console?

Comment: @thepio I am using angular1

Comment: Look At This Link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055251/sending-data-with-angularjs-http-delete-request

Comment: Also, while sending DELETE requests Content-Type header is not required because these requests do not (and should not) have a body.

Comment: Sir I tested this in Advaced rest client by giving url http:// abc/users/users/1 and used delete method it does delete the comment.

Comment: I already went through the link I am new to angular so things are very complex for me to undnerstand

Comment: I am getting 404 error in console btw

Comment: I removed the  headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        } still no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the API, as the API is written in Yii framework and in the main.config file where we define the rules there were spaces                 `array('users / delete', 'pattern' => 'users / <model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb' => 'DELETE'),` like this I removed the spaces and it worked.

Final rule

```
array('users/delete', 'pattern' => 'users/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb' => 'DELETE'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `404` means you have `not defined the DELETE method API`
at the back-end.

First of all defined it.