# How to see the HTTP request that AngularJS is sending?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, curl, httprequest

I have a REST endpoint called `myEndpoint` that I can successfully hit using Curl like this:

```
curl \
--request DELETE \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: JWT eyJhbFciOiJ__FAKE__sInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhcWliIi__FAKE__9pZCI6NSwiZW1haWwiOiJzYXFpYi5hbGkuNzVAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNDkxNzkyMzEzfQ.feGiXm__FAKE__ZS6V-OROM7EzekRzpu_5pwi865tz8" \
--data '{
    "myAttribute": "Something"
}' \
"http://localhost:3999/api/myEndpoint"
```

However, when my AngularJS code tries to call the same endpoint it fails saying that the mandatory `myAttribute` parameter was not provided. This is how angularJS is making the call:

```
  var httpParams = {'myAttribute': 'Something'};
  $scope.myPromise = $http.delete('http://localhost:3999/api/myEndpoint', httpParams).then(self.myEndpointSuccess, self.myEndpointFailure);
```

(AngularJS's attachment of the JWT token to the HTTP request is not shown, but I'm sure that is working)

How can I see exactly what HTTP request AngularJS is sending so that I can do an apples-to-apples comparison agains my working curl call?

Here is my Chrome's Developer[image] Tools -> Network tab. I don't see the information I'm seeking there:

Comment: browser developer tools network tab?

Comment: Jaromanda, See the original question. I added in a screenshot of the Network tab. But I don't see the information I need. What am I missing??

Comment: `What am I missing` - the request - perhaps select **All** rather than **Other**

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Yes, that worked. Follow up question: It shows no `myAtttribute` parameter being sent. How do I send that parameter with a `DELETE` request. The code above works for POST methods. But apparently not for DELETEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $ http service documentation says that $ http.delete gets two parameters, URL and config. By its call curl, I understand that myAtribute is the name given to a parameter that you want to send to the endpoint, in which case it should be in the params property or data property of the config object.

[angular reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete)
[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055251/how-to-send-data-with-angularjs-http-delete-request)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, `DELETE` requests do not typically have a request body.

As for your issue, [RTFM](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete); the second arg to `$http.delete` should be a config object, so in your case

```
$http.delete('http://localhost:3999/api/myEndpoint', {data: httpParams})
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS provides the $http module for http requests. You can make a specific request with this module and then process the request with the . then() whichever takes a success callback followed by a error callback