# Delete request with HTML - AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know that HTML does not support anything other than POST and GET.

I have a app that works when I send a DELETE request via POSTMAN. But when I try with ng-submit or ng-click that calls a function delete, it does not work.

How can I achive this delete request in-code ? Is that possible to create a button that does a DELETE request ? I am using AngularJS.

This is what I have created: (index.html)

```
<md-button ng-click="delete()">Delete everything.</md-button>
```

This is the app.js that calls the function delete:

```
      $scope.delete = function(index) {
      var data = {
         "id" : $scope.pollData[index].id,
         "option" : $scope.pollData[index].selected
       };
      $http.delete("/polls",data).success(function(response) {
      if(response.responseCode === 0) {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log("IvanUspeh");
        $scope.hiddenrows.push(index);
      } else {
        console.log("error");
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055251/how-to-send-data-with-angularjs-http-delete-request

Answer (score 0):

Send your data to the with request params, syntax below.

```
  http.delete("/some/url", { 
        params: {
              "foo": "bar"
        }
  });
```

At the minute I don't think your api is accessing the request payload you're sending up.

In node/express I would access the params via

```
  app.delete("/some/url", (req, res) => {

         let foo = req.query.foo;
         //foo = "bar"

  });
```