# How to edit a cell and delete a row by clicking icon in Angular JS 1.3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Still be a angular learner.

I have my page like
[image: 1]

The code is:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
    <div>
        <h2 align="center">Angular JS Basic Example</h2>
        <h5 align="center">Employee List</h5>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Edit
                </th>
                <th>
                    Employee Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Employee Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Address
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Delete
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{emp.EmployeeId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{emp.EmployeeName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{emp.Address}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{emp.EmailId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" 
                       onclick="return confirm('Delete this Employee?');"
                       class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the js code for getting all employees. It works well.

```
app.controller("EmpCtrl", function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
GetAllEmployee();

function GetAllEmployee() {

    var getAllEmployee = EmployeeService.getEmployee();
    getAllEmployee.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.employees = emp.data;
    }, function () {
        alert('Data not found');
    });
 }
});
```

My asp mvc service code to delete methos is

```
 [HttpDelete]
    public void DeleteEmployee(int id)
    {
        using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var employeeList = db.EmployeeModels.ToList();
            var temp = employeeList.Find(x => x.EmployeeId == id);
            employeeList.Remove(temp);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I want to click the edit/delete icon to edit or delete, I guess that I have to add other javascript functions to do that.(Maybe ng-clcik??) But I don't know exactly, so how to edit a cell or delete a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//html
<td>
 <a href="#" 
    ng-click="delFn(emp.EmployeeId,$index)"
    class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
  </a>
</td>

//this way u can achieve it
$scope.delFn = function(id, index){
    var response = confirm('Delete this Employee?');
    if(response) {
       $http.delete('url/' + id).then(function(result) {
          result.data ? $scope.employees.splice(index, 1) : null;
       }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how your UI looks. Delete is easy, just declare a function in your controller and pass the index of the row to the function like this:

In your controller:

```
$scope.delFn = function(index){
     var response = confirm('Delete this Employee?');
     if(response) {
     $scope.employees.splice(index, 1);
   }
}
```

In your view: instead of onclick, use ng-click

```
  <td>
     <a href="#" 
        ng-click="delFn($index)"
        class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
      </a>
  </td>
```

where $index is implicitly available from ng-repeat. Or you can do this to make it explicit stated.

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in employees track by $index">
```

Can you figure out the edit yourself? since you are using table tag. It looks like you can make a popup/modal, pass in the index of the row in your edit function, get the selected employee from $scope.employees, display the selected one in the popup and make it editable with input tag.

Comment: Basically it works on client side, I have to save the change to the db. How to hook up my service code? I updated the code. Thanks.

Comment: You know which employee to delete, so you should know their id? And since the mvc api is expecting an id, you can just send the id in the query parameter? I am assuming you have the delete function working correctly in EmployeeService and your data contains id of each employees.

Comment: Delete function is working, but I think that I need `$http.delete` in my service.js code. I am not sure how it is implemented. I need that piece of code.

Comment: if all you need is a simple $http delete, I believe there are many posts on stackoverflow related to that? something like this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055251/how-to-send-data-with-angularjs-http-delete-request

Comment: if you still have problem implementing the $http delete, you should make another post to ask for help for that particular delete function and show why it doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" 
    ng-click="delFn(emp.EmployeeId)"
    class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

//this way u can achieve it

```
$scope.delFn = function(id){

   EmployeeService.delEmployee(id).then(function (data) {
        GetAllEmployee();
    }, function () {
        alert('Data not found');
    });
}
```

then add service

```
this.delEmployee= function (id) {
        return $http.post('controller/delEmployee', data={id:id});            
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it is correctly if using `$http.post`. It should be `$http.delete`.

Comment: this.delEmployee= function (id) {return $http.delete('controller/delEmployee', data={id:id})};

Comment: u can use http post for delete as well no need to use delete its not a must and when using post what error u got